# Want to read integer from a textfile

Tags: c++, string, integer

So my problem is, when i read the file the "ki" , "kivel" and the "meddig" variables are good, but the "mettol" variable seems like it is disappeared.

```
struct Haboru {
    string ki;
    string kivel;
    int mettol;
    int meddig;
};

int main()
{
    Haboru haboruk[10];
    int k = 0;
    ifstream haboru;
    haboru.open("haboruk.txt");
    // The rows are in "haboruk.txt" like these:
    // Xhosa Zulu 1696 1736
    // Zulu Ndebele 1752 1782
    // Zulu Sotho 1756 1772
    while(!haboru.eof())
    {
        haboru >> haboruk[k].ki >> haboruk[k].kivel >> haboruk[k].mettol >> haboruk[k].meddig;
        k++;
    }
}
```

The output is this:
[image]

Comment: Add some debug prints in the loop, to print the values as they are read. Then, add that output to question.

Comment: Hey, thanks for accepting my answer! Quick question: Did my code work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `!file.eof()` as a condition to extract is not correct. You have to perform the extraction, and *then* check if the file is valid. But even using `!file.eof()` afterwards is still not correct:

Let's make this simpler by creating an inserter for a `Haboru` object:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Haboru& haboruk)
{
    if (!is.good())
        return is;

    is >> haboruk.ki;
    is >> haboruk.kivel;
    is >> haboruk.mettol >> haboruk.meddig;

    return is;
}
```

Then you can create your vector (or `std::array` <kbd>C++11</kbd>) and use the inserter for each element:

```
std::vector<Haboru> haboruks;
Haboru haboruk;

while (haboru >> haboruk)
{
    haboruks.push_back(haboruk);
}
```

Or...

```
std::vector<Haboru> haboruks((std::istream_iterator<Haboru>(haboru)),
                              std::istream_iterator<Haboru>());
```